# Apple review reject because get user permission dialog locoalized

Tags: ios, objective-c, location

The reject email says:

```
Guideline 4.0 - Design  
We noticed an issue in your app that contributes to a lower quality user 

experience than Apple users expect: 

- Your app's modal alerts are in English, but your app's primary language is Chinese. To help users understand why your app is requesting access to a specific feature, your app's modal alerts should be in the same language as the rest of your app.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to address all instances of this type of issue.
```

And I have customized dialog to show why app need to get user's location.

Then I add some localizations in project.
[image: localization]

`InfoPlist.string (Base)`

> "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "Allow the App to activate GPS service for providing service related information.";

`InfoPlist.string (English)`

> "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "Allow the App to activate GPS service for providing service related information.";

`InfoPlist.string (Chinese (Traditional))`

> "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "開啟您的「定位服務」以允許「我的APP」提供資訊查詢服務。";

`InfoPlist.string (Chinese (Simplified))`

> "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "開啟您的「定位服務」以允許「我的APP」提供資訊查詢服務。";

How to fix this issue to fit the review?

And if I only change device language to Japanese, the dialog will show Chinese (Traditional).
Have any idea to make dialog to show English not Chinese when my device language is Japanese?

Comment: try to make base "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" on Chinese, because your base language is Chinese

Answer (score 0):

**First thing:**
 Apple says **To help users understand why your app is requesting access to a specific feature, your app's modal alerts *should be* in the same language as the rest of your app.**

**Second thing:**
But as you don't want to add Japanese language localization in your device, you will be able to see only Chinese language translation text as it is your Primary language in case you switch your device's language to any other language other than the provided localization (Chinese and English).

**Third thing: (Your requirement)**

1. Show English(which is not even primary language) language messages in case of any other device language selection than (Chinese and English).
2. Pass the test given by Apple to get your app approved given in the first thing.

You have to do following things to achieve this:

1. As you cannot modify your info.plist on runtime and therefore you cannot modify *NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription* key. You cannot achieve this, else you have to modify your App's primary language or provide separate localization for Japanese as well. Although if you do so, you will have to keep the same data in both localizable.strings files but different data in info.plist files, where you can change *NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription* key's value in English. But again your app has huge no of chances to get rejected as Apple reads your localization from lproj folder and it may find that you are giving Chinese and English texts in your app and plist files respectively. So you definitely will have to change your app requirements in this case. But you can give it a try and appeal from Apple specifying your app's requirement.
2. For your second requirement, by analysis, I come to the conclusion that you have to do either of the two things:

   1. Set **Localization native development region** as "zh-Hant" and "zh-Hans" in traditional and simplified chinese respectively instead of $(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE). Also "en" in case of English.
   2. Make base on Chinese as your primary language is Chinese.